# change contetnt of a div to another cods with another divs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wan to when I click on my favorite button the content of a div that named id=content change to my favorite code with another divs. 
I don't know I should use jquery Ajax or what?
This is my code:
I don't know what exactly I do to get my point.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/external/_oldies/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//what should i write here?

});
});
</script>

<style>


<body>
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
<strong>MERAJ GAZ<span>branch num2</span> </strong>

</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li>
<a id="product">product</a>
</li>
<li>
adress
</li>
<li>
our succsess
</li>
<li>
contact us
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear-fix">
</div>
<div class="content" >
<div class="meraj">
<img src="absolute.png" />
</div>
<div id="content">
<img id="img" src="IMG_0375.JPG" width="822" height="400" style="-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-top:none;"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear-fix">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//include jQuery to your page. 
<a href="#" id="aFavourite" > Favorite <a/>
<div id="divDescr"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

  $("#aFavourite").click(function(){
     $("#divDescr").html("<p>Some other content loaded now</p>");
  });

})
```

If you want to load some content from your server page, you can use a jquery ajax call to do so

Example with using the `load` function

```
  $("#aFavourite").click(function(){
     $("#divDescr").load("myserverpage.php");
  });
```

Comment: tanx my friend but i want to load another contents on my favorite div

Comment: @babakfaghihian: Do the same thing in that div.

Comment: tanx my friend  i wanna to make a slidshow in my div can u help me?

Comment: @babakfaghihian  post more details as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this? When I click button, the content of a div is changed:

http://jsfiddle.net/mhtdA/

Basically I'm calling function .click() of element with id "button" and then replacing already existing html content of that div.